# Use Java streams to get nth element from a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Strings such as `"/100" "/100/200"`.
I wish to split these strings by `/`, and would then get a List of List of Integers such as `[[100],[100,200]]`.
I want to traverse this list of list and get nth element from each list if that list is long enough, else move to the next list.

It is known that each inner list would be maximum of length `n`.

Example :

```
n= 3
slashString -> "/100/200/300","/200/300","/100/200/400"
```

In the above case I want a List of Integers as `300,400`.

```
List<Integer> output = slashString.stream()
        .map(x->Arrays.stream(x.split("/")).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(x->x.size()==3)
```

I am able to think till above. How would I eventually collect the 3rd element across all the list of integers.

Answer (score 4):

Just map each `List` to the 3rd element of the `List` and collect:

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.of ("100/200/300","200/300","100/200/400")
    .map(x->Arrays.stream(x.split("/")).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .filter(x->x.size()==3)
    .map(l->Integer.valueOf (l.get(2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you have to eliminate the leading `/` of the input `String`s. Otherwise the lengths of the 1st and 3rd `List`s will be 4, and they won't pass the filter. Or you can require the `List` size to be 4 instead of 3 (and change `l.get(2)` to `l.get(3)`).

Comment: match better is `int index = 3;
List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList("/100/200/300", "/200/300", "/100/200/400").stream()
        .map(m -> Arrays.stream(m.split("/")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(l -> l.size() == index)
        .map(l -> Integer.valueOf(l.get(index - 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Note the `filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())` this will ignore the empty result in the beginning which mean the `index` should be `3` and not `4`

Comment: @YCF_L Oh, I missed that change. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there.

After filtering list of size 3, get the third element and convert it to an Integer.

Also, note that splitting a String `/100/200` will give you a `String[]` (`["", "100", "200"]`) with an *empty string* as the first element. So, I have skipped the first element using `skip(1)`

```
List<Integer> result = slashString.stream()
            .map(x-> Arrays.stream(x.split("/"))
                    .skip(1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .filter(x -> x.size() >= 3)
            .map(list -> Integer.valueOf(list.get(2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove all but the third term using regex, filter out empties, voila!

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.of("100/200/300", "200/300", "100/200/400")
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("^([^/]/[^/]/)?([^/]+)?(/.*)?", "$2"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .map(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The regex always matches the whole string, and replaces it with the 3rd term, which was captured as group 2, but because everything is optional, group 2 (the final result) is blank if there isn’t a 3rd term.

This approach only ever deals with Strings, which keeps things simpler by avoiding ugly array code.

Comment: Regular expressions are hard to maintain. First, it seems you forgot the quantifiers in the first group, as matching exactly one non-`/` character doesn’t fit the intended use case. You surely meant `[^/]*` instead of `[^/]`. The second problem is that you made the first group optional, so for `200/300`, it doesn’t match the first group (doesn’t end with slash), so the subsequent group will capture the 1st number instead of being empty. I’d rather use: `.replaceFirst("([^/]*+/?+){0,2}+([^/]*).*", "$2")`, this will not only fix these issues, it allows easy adaptation to support the “n’th” item.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to make intermediate lists.  Instead turn each string into a stream that's either empty or contains just the nth element with `skip(n).limit(1)` and use `flatMap` to merge all the little streams together:

```
Pattern delimiter = Pattern.compile("/");
int n = 3;

List<Integer> result = slashString.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> delimiter.splitAsStream(s).skip(n).limit(1))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(toList());
```